# async functions in completion at point functions?

Tags: completion, async

in my library, i have completion backends that i add to `completion-at-point-functions` as per the docs, but my completion candidates are fetched from a server with an http request. the call is very slow, and i would like to make it asynchronous. ideally completion wouldn't interrupt user input at all.

from what i can see, `completion-at-point-functions` can't seem to handle an async response, say with `aio.el` and writing callbacks, for example with `url-retrieve` won't work with it either.

is there any way the two features can be made to play with each other nicely?

Answer (score 2):

looks like using `while-no-input` is the simplest way to go. i received advice from capf guru extraordinaire minad to this effect:

```
(list start
      end
      ;; only search when necessary:
      (completion-table-dynamic
       (lambda (_)
         ;; Interruptible candidate computation
         (let ((result
                (while-no-input
                  (your-fetch-candidates-function start end))))
           (and (consp result) result))))
      :exclusive 'no
      :annotation-function
      (lambda (candidate)
        (concat " "
                (your-annotation-function candidate))))
```